# how to print unhandled exception to console instead of browser in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, myfaces

I want unhandled exceptions to be printed to console so that I can just click on exception to go to the line causing exception. 
But they are printed to the browser and I couldn't find any setting for that.
I am using JSF 2.2 with myfaces implementation and tomcat as container.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a special page for exceptions instead of showing exceptions. The exception trace will still be written into the log but it will not be displayed to users.

**web.xml**

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/errorpages/404.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.ejb.EJBException</exception-type> // Your exception type
    <location>/errorpages/404.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: My problem is not about users seeing the error . I just wanted to see stack trace in console. Turns out it was because of `Development` `PROJECT_STAGE`. It is ironic that now I use `Production` for developing and `Development` for launch version